# JSF FacesMessage will not be renderd

Tags: forms, validation, jsf, error-handling, rendering

I already read a lot of guides how to add a FacesMessage but nothing worked and i do not understand why?

I always get the following warning, but I do not now how to fix it?

```
[Warnung ] There are some unhandled FacesMessages, this means not every FacesMessage had a chance to be rendered.
These unhandled FacesMessages are: 
- Login failed
```

My JSF View:

```
    <!-- Login Form -->
        <h:form id="loginForm" role="form" style="width: 400px; margin:0 auto;">
            <div class="required-field-block">
                <h:outputLabel for="email" value="Email-Adresse"></h:outputLabel>
                <h:inputText id="email" label="Email" value="#{loginBean.email}" class="form-control" required="true" requiredMessage="Keine Mailadresse angeben"></h:inputText>
                <h:message for="email" class="text text-danger"></h:message>
            </div>
            <div class="required-field-block">
                <h:outputLabel for="password" value="Passwort"></h:outputLabel>
                <h:inputText id="password" label="Passwort" value="#{loginBean.password}" class="form-control" required="true" requiredMessage="Kein Passwort angegeben"></h:inputText>
                <h:message for="password" class="text text-danger"></h:message>
            </div>
            <h:commandButton  id="sendLogin" update="loginForm" value="Login" type="submit" actionListener="#{loginBean.login}" class="btn btn-primary"></h:commandButton>
            <h:message globalOnly="true"></h:message>
        </h:form>
```

And my code from the bean:

```
    public String login() {
    UserManagement man = new UserManagement();
    try {
        user = man.getUserByEmail(this.email);
    } catch (SQLException | IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        String msg = "Login failed";
        addErrorMessage(msg);
        return "loginFailed";
    }

    if(this.user!=null&&this.user.getPassword().equals(password)) {
        this.loggedIn = true;
        return "loginSucceed";
    }
    else {
        String msg = "Unvalid Password";
        addErrorMessage(msg);
        return "loginFailed";
    }
}

private void addErrorMessage(String msg) {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    FacesMessage fm = new FacesMessage(msg);
    context.addMessage(null, fm);
}
```

What am i doing wrong? Why the hell is this message not renderd? I am a bit desperated because I tried everything with ID, globally but nothing worked and I am stumped why it does not work. Maybe it is just a dumb mistake i have not seen all the time :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `h:message` component renders only a single message from a component you have to refere to using the `for` attribute.

If you want to render ALL message, just use `h:messages` instead:

```
<h:messages/>
```

This should work fine for your usecase.